# Boost.TTI not working with Clang

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, introspection

Boost 1.54 added a new library, [**Boost.TTI**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/index.html) for **type traits introspection**. The following code using the [**`has_template`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_template/tti_detail_has_template_metafunction.html) functionality, works on g++ but not on Clang

```
#include <boost/tti/has_template.hpp>

BOOST_TTI_HAS_TEMPLATE(Template1)
BOOST_TTI_HAS_TEMPLATE(Template2)
BOOST_TTI_HAS_TEMPLATE(Template3)

struct Top
{
  template <class X> struct Template1 { };
  template <typename A,typename B,typename C> class Template2 { };
  template <typename A,typename B,typename C,int D> class Template3 { };
};

int main()
{
    static_assert( has_template_Template1<Top>::value, ""); // true
    static_assert( has_template_Template2<Top>::value, ""); // true
    static_assert(!has_template_Template3<Top>::value, ""); // false, not all typename/class template parameters
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e35959a7ca56433).

**Question**: why doesn't this code compile on Clang? According to the Boost.TTI docs, support for variadic macros is required, but Clang has been supporting that since 2.9.

Comment: Using `#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` makes it work. I don't know why it is not being detected automatically.

Comment: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-variadic-BOOST-PP-TUPLE-REM-in-Clang-tp4654884p4654904.html

Comment: @cv_and_he tnx! If you could make that an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOST_TTI_HAS_TEMPLATE` uses variadic macros from Boost.Preprocessor. [The maintainer of this library does not want to depend on Boost.Config and also believes that the macro that Config defines is not "strong enough" for a preprocessor metaprogramming library.](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-variadic-BOOST-PP-TUPLE-REM-in-Clang-tp4654884p4655146.html). For these reasons the use of the variadic versions of `BOOST_TTI_HAS_TEMPLATE` depends on whether `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS` is defined. [Sadly, the code for automatically determining if a compiler has variadic macro support is out of date and does not include clang amongst the compilers for which variadic support is on. The recommended workaround is defining `BOOST_PP_VARIADICS=1`.](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-variadic-BOOST-PP-TUPLE-REM-in-Clang-tp4654884p4654904.html)

Apparently this has been solved in trunk, and may possibly be included in a future release.

Comment: Btw, just curious: why do you make all your answers community-wiki?

Comment: Two reasons: the main one, I don't want to get to 125 rep (ability to downvote) and the other one, I'm not confident in my ability to express myself clearly in English (<-Exhibit 1), and by making them community wiki almost anyone can edit any errors I make.